# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable"

Tags: json, scala, serialization, spark-streaming

iam getting the above error while running the below code. i observed that there is some serializable problem but i cudn't trace out exactly. can any one explain what can i do here. thanks in advance.

```
 enter code here 



    def checkforType(json:String):String={
            val  parsedjson = parse(json)
               val res=(parsedjson \\ "Head" \\ "Type" ).extract[String]
               (res)      
           }
    val dstream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, Map("topic" -> 1)).map(_._2)
           val pType = dstream.map(checkforType)
           pType.map(rdd => {
           val pkt= rdd.toString()
          if(pkt.equals("P300")) {

          val t300=dstream.map(par300)
           t300.print()
         }else if(pkt.equals("P30")) {
            val t30=dstream.map(par30)
            t30.print()        
         }else if(pkt.equals("P6")) {
            val t6=dstream.map(par6)
            t6.print()        
         }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This mainly happens when you are passing the object to the transformation and that object is not serializable.

I found one interesting post on this : https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-sparkexception-task-not-serializable.html

Maybe this can solve your problem. 
Thanks !